# * Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "E:\Flutter\login_demo\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, dart

So guys i'am newbie at Flutter and i have my Flutter Project using Firebase Auth for user login. I have following the tutorial from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaKef60iuy8 by guy called Andrea Bizzotto. I have follow 3 part of his videos regarding to this Firbase Auth tutorial. He suggest to latest firebase_auth dependecies, and according to pub.dev the latest dependecies of firebase_auth is
0.15.0+1, but he use the 0.5.4. However, if i use the 0.15.0+1 one i got some error at FirebaseAuth.instance, so i use the 0.5.4 dependecies. But it caused error to my gradle when building the project. The debug console throw me this:

> [Debug Console Error Message][1]

And before make this post, i have tried to find any solution regarding to this error. **So what have tried to do is:**

1. Adding

   > **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'** and changing **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'** to
   >   **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'** in (android/build.gradle)
2. Adding

   > **multidexEnabled = true** at defaultConfig, **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0' implementation
   >   'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0' implementation
   >   'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'** at dependencies also **apply
   >   plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** at the bottom of
   >   (android\app\buid.gradle) file
3. I'm also adding

   > **android.useAndroidX=true
   >       android.enableJetifier=true
   >       org.gradle.daemon=true
   >       org.gradle.parallel=true** in gradle.properties file

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` result
[Flutter doctor -v Result][2]

Any Help is very much appreciated.

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60j9S.png [2]:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G8ug.png

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update the build.grade from project root like this:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


}
```

}

and then the distributionUrl in grade-wrapper.properties like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

I got the answer from here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41492